# How to create list button in iphone like this?

Tags: ios4

i am new to this development field in iphone and i want to create list button like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi2sP.png]

according to above image i want to create custom object in Xcode 
how can i implement it?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about “list button” so I guess you want a “list”, i.e. a table view.

You can have a look at UITableViewCell, and more specifically to its imageView, textLabel and detailedTextLabel properties which look like what you want to achieve.

Useful documentation from Apple about tableView cells can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

Answer (score 0):

Either you create and position your buttons with Interface Builder, either you change the CGRect associated with each UIButton.

For eg : UIButton *b1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:(x,y,w,h)];